# Is it okay to perform a dua in Other than Arabic language?

Tags: arabic, dua

I want to make dua, But I barely understand Arabic. is it okay if I make dua in My First language ?

Comment: Yeah it is indeed it is necessary to make dua in your own language,, see this http://seekershub.org/podcast/2015/12/02/dua-in-my-own-language/

Answer (score 0):

You can make du'aa in any language (even in salat, when there is a need).
This was stated by: 
Shaykh al-Islam Ibn Taymiyah (Majmoo’ al-Fataawa, 22/488-489):

> It is permissible to make du’aa’ (supplication) in Arabic and in
>   languages other than Arabic. Allaah knows the intention of the
>   supplicant and what he wants, no matter what language he speaks,
>   because He hears all the voices in all different languages, asking for
>   all kinds of needs.